# How to use numba.vectorize function with an argument being a sequence of floats

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I am trying to optimize some code and looking for ways to make make a [numpy universal function](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/vectorize.html) with numba.

The original function has the following signature

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, vectorize
from typing import Sequence

@njit
def f(x: float, y: Sequence[float], z:float = 1e-14) -> float:
    """Computations are only exemplarily"""

    a = np.sum(y)
    if np.abs(x - a) < z:
        return 0.
    else:
        return np.abs(x - a)
```

which works as expected.

I would like use `numba.vectorize` to create an universal function s.t. `f` can be called with

```
x: np.ndarray | float, y: Sequence[np.ndarray | float], z: float
```

Also, `f` is created in some other part of the code, i.e. the length of `y` varies, but is known at the time of definition of `f`.

One obvious solution is to make another function which takes (possibly) vectorized input
and do some operations inside using `numba.prange` to fil up the result vector.

But I am looking for a more elegant solution using `numba.vectorize` and I don't want to deal with
broadcasting, since `x` can be a float, or an element of `y` can be a float.

Best regards,

I tried

```
 f_v = vectorize(
     [
         numba.float64(
             numba.float64,
             numba.float64[:],
             numba.float64,
         )
     ],
     nopython=True,
)(f)
```

But it failed to compile, no matching signature found.

**Edit:**
`f` performs simple arithmetics on scalars. I inserted some dummy computations since the originals are rather lengthy.
The vectorized version should perform those computations component-wise and return an array.

Comment: `tuple[float]` represents a tuple of length 1 (e.g. `(0.0,)` ). Is it `tuple[float, ...]` or `list[float]` ? Can you provide reproducible code to better understand what you actually want to do?

Comment: @ken I modified it to a general sequence, hoping I would better illustrate what I want.
I added also some dummy computations.

Comment: `y` could be arrays of different lengths like `[np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4,5])]` ? Or is it just a 2D array of unknown shape?

Comment: If elements of `y` are arrays, they should all be of same length.
In above example, numpy would through a broadcasting error if they were of different length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use guvectorize instead of vectorize.

```py
@numba.guvectorize("(float64, float64[:], float64, float64[:])", "(),(n),()->()", target="parallel")
def f_vectorized(x, y, z, out):
    out[0] = f(x, y, z)


result1 = f_vectorized(1.0, np.array([1.0, 2.0]), 1e-14)
result2 = f_vectorized(np.array([1.0]), np.array([[1.0, 2.0]]), 1e-14)
result3 = f_vectorized(np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]), np.array([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]]), 1e-14)
result4 = f_vectorized(np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]), [np.array([1.0, 2.0]), np.array([3.0, 4.0]), np.array([5.0, 6.0])], 1e-14)
```

However, there are two issues to consider.

The first is obvious: `z` cannot have a default value.
To get around this, you have to create another function.

```py
def f_vectorized_with_default_value(x, y, z=1e-14):
    return f_vectorized(x, y, z)
```

The second is more critical: it does not work well if `y` is a python list of numpy arrays. That is, this case:

```py
result4 = f_vectorized(np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]), [np.array([1.0, 2.0]), np.array([3.0, 4.0]), np.array([5.0, 6.0])], 1e-14)
```

Here is the benchmark code.

```py
import time
import timeit
import warnings

import numpy as np
from typing import Sequence
import numba


@numba.njit(cache=True)
def f(x: float, y: Sequence[float], z: float = 1e-14) -> float:
    """Computations are only exemplarily"""

    a = np.sum(y)
    if np.abs(x - a) < z:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return np.abs(x - a)


@numba.njit(parallel=True, cache=True)
def f_prange(x, y, z):
    """Implementation with prange as a baseline."""
    n = len(x)
    out = np.empty(n, dtype=x.dtype)
    for i in numba.prange(n):
        out[i] = f(x[i], y[i], z)
    return out


def f_loop(x, y, z):
    """Another baseline."""
    n = len(x)
    out = np.empty(n, dtype=x.dtype)
    for i in range(n):
        out[i] = f(x[i], y[i], z)
    return out


@numba.guvectorize("(float64, float64[:], float64, float64[:])", "(),(n),()->()", target="parallel", cache=True)
def f_vectorized(x, y, z, out):
    out[0] = f(x, y, z)


def f_vectorized_with_default_value(x, y, z=1e-14):
    return f_vectorized(x, y, z)


def test(title, func, x, y, z, expected, number=10):
    assert np.array_equal(func(x, y, z), expected)
    elapsed = timeit.timeit(lambda: func(x, y, z), number=number) / number
    print(f"{title}: {elapsed}")


def main():
    rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
    n = 1000000
    m = 1000

    x = rng.random(size=(n,), dtype=np.float64)
    y_as_numpy = rng.random(size=(n, m), dtype=np.float64)
    y_as_list = [y_as_numpy[i] for i in range(n)]
    z = 1e-14

    started = time.perf_counter()
    _ = np.array(y_as_list)
    print("merge into a np array:", time.perf_counter() - started)

    started = time.perf_counter()
    y_as_typed_list = numba.typed.List(y_as_list)
    print("convert to typed list:", time.perf_counter() - started)

    expected = f(x[0], y_as_numpy[0], z)
    test("f(single)", f, x[0], y_as_numpy[0], z, expected)
    test("f_vectorized(single)", f_vectorized, x[0], y_as_numpy[0], z, expected)

    expected = f_prange(x, y_as_numpy, z)
    test("f_prange(numpy)", f_prange, x, y_as_numpy, z, expected)
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore", numba.NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning)
        test("f_prange(python_list)", f_prange, x, y_as_list, z, expected)
    test("f_prange(typed_list)", f_prange, x, y_as_typed_list, z, expected)
    test("f_loop(python_list)", f_loop, x, y_as_list, z, expected)
    test("f_vectorized(numpy)", f_vectorized, x, y_as_numpy, z, expected)
    test("f_vectorized(python_list)", f_vectorized, x, y_as_list, z, expected)
    test("f_vectorized(typed_list)", f_vectorized, x, y_as_typed_list, z, expected)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

```
merge into a np array: 1.3248698
convert to typed list: 1.6472616999999996
f(single): 1.430000000013365e-06
f_vectorized(single): 1.6320000000025204e-05
f_prange(numpy): 0.18999052999999985
f_prange(python_list): 7.21668874
f_prange(typed_list): 0.20048094999999932 + (convert to typed list)
f_loop(python_list): 1.3346305299999996
f_vectorized(numpy): 0.18892754000000025
f_vectorized(python_list): 1.8655723899999999
f_vectorized(typed_list): 3.323696179999999 + (convert to typed list)
```

As you can see from the last two lines of results, it is very slow. It works, but slow.
In fact, it is faster to call the `f` function sequentially in a python loop (not `numba.prange`, pure python loop).

If `y` is a 2D numpy array in the first place, this will not bother you. `f_vectorized` should work fine.
But if it is a python list, you might have to find another trick.

Comment: `f_vectorized(numpy)` is objectively the best option then.

Thank you very much!